# Trying Brute Force technique to solve a leetcode question but gives an error

Tags: java, data-structures, brute-force

Here is the link to the problem statement: https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/

I am trying to solve this question using brute force technique. The code works fine for most of the test cases but is giving an error for the following test case: [2,3,4,5,18,17,6]

This is the code implementation

```
    public int maxArea(int[] height) {
        int Area = 0;
        int maxArea = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < height.length ; i++)
       {
           for(int j = 1 ; j < height.length ; j++)
           {
               if(height[i] > height[j])
                   maxArea = height[j] * (j-i);
               else
                   maxArea = height[i] * (j-i);
           }
           Area = Math.max(maxArea,Area);
       }
        return Area;
    }
}

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance
```

Comment: and what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

What basicly happens with case: [2,3,4,5,18,17,6] is that when the loop get to i=4 and j=5 -> The correct maxArea 17 is saved.
The problem is that on the next j loop: i=4, j=6 -> we get to the numbers 18 and 6.

Since 18 is bigger than 6 you set maxArea to a new value which is 12 (6*2) and overwrite our desired maxArea to save.

---

**Edit**

I found a change that would make it work by only making some changes to the inner j loop:

```
           for(int j = 1 ; j < height.length ; j++)
           {
                if(height[i] > height[j]){
                    if ((height[j] * (j-i)) > maxArea)
                       maxArea = height[j] * (j-i);}
                else 
                    maxArea = height[i] * (j-i);
           }
```

I added an inner if statement that actually apply the new maxArea only if it's bigger than the current one, otherwise - do nothing.

It worked for me with your special case and the example test cases on leetcode.

Also as a sidenote, I'd like to suggest getting used to using a Debugger, it's a tool IDEs has that allow you to run your code step by step(loop after loop) and see the variables values after each change ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gAjIQc4bPU)'s a video that helped me with understanding how it works, in Eclipse).